# Java Hibernate Generic DAO with mode attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, dao

I am in the process of writing **abstract/generic** DAO functions to perform Hibernate create, update, find, delete queries.

In case of the update function, I want to check whether a particular attribute called **mode** is set to 0 which means the record is updateable (0-read/Write, 1- deleted, 2-read only).
As a result I need to access the **getMode** Function of the Object, so I cannot simply call a generic update function, which does not know about the existence of that attribute.

How can I manage to write a **generic update function** which assumes the existence of an attribute mode, is it possible at all ?

```
session = factory.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
if(at.getMode() == 0){
   session.update(at);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar situation before. In a system I worked on, all tables had a last updated timestamp, so whenever a update occurred, a generic method updated the field with the current time and after that the update was performed.

Please bear in mind that this is probably not the only solution.

In my case all entities implemented an Interface. For your case the Interface should be something like this:

```
public interface HasModeAttribute {

//assumed mode is an int
int getMode();

}
```

In your generic DAO all you have to do is to properly declare a generic method that accepts all Classes that implements this interface:

```
(...)
    //omitted class declaration here 
    public <T extends HasModeAttribute> void yourUpdate(T entity) {
        session = factory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        if(entity.getMode() == 0){
           session.update(entity);
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

(...)
```

And that's it.

The downside of this solution is that you have to make all your entities implement this new Interface, but I consider this a small price. The upside is that all of this will be checked by the compiler.

Comment: You could always check if the given entity has implemented that interface by checking if entity is an instance of the interface.

Comment: This should work too. It's a simpler approach, but then you have to consider what to do if the entity does not implement the interface. Will update it anyway? Throw an exception? Not a big deal, but using generics you ensure that this will only be performed on a specific group of entities.